# Adding background image using MUI in next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

Notice that English is my second language.

This is next.js 14.
I am trying to create a search engine home page.
And I am trying to import a background image with a dark filter on it under the search bar.
I somehow implemented but the code looks stupid: I did not use "next/image", I made separate box to filter the image. Can anyone provide smarter way to do this?

```
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import backgroundImage from "public/assets/home_bg/background.jpg";
import SearchBar from "@/app/components/SearchBar";
import Image from "next/image";

export default function HomePage() {
  return (
    <Box
      className="index-header text-center"
      style={{
        backgroundImage: `url(${backgroundImage.src})`,
        backgroundSize: "cover",
        backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
        height: "500px",
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
      }}
    >
      <Box
        sx={{ zIndex: 500 }}
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          left: 0,
          width: "100%",
          height: "500px",
          background: "rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5)",
        }}
      />
      <Box
        className="mt-4 container"
        sx={{ zIndex: 1000 }}
        style={{
          width: "100%",
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
      >
        <Typography
          variant="h1"
          style={{
            color: "white",
            fontWeight: "bold",
          }}
        >
          Title
        </Typography>
        <Typography
          variant="body2"
          style={{
            marginTop: "0px",
            marginBottom: "50px",
            color: "white",
            fontSize: "20px",
          }}
        >
          Sub-title
        </Typography>

        <Box style={{ width: "30%" }}>
          <SearchBar />
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a Background image in NextJS in the right way using NextJS Image it's more simple than it looks, you just need to create a parent component with the right position ***'relative'*** or ***'absolute'***, and add the **fill** attribute in the Image tag, in that case, it's not necessary to add width and height in the Image.

```
import { Box, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import Image from 'next/image';
import SearchBar from '@/app/components/SearchBar';

export default function HomePage() {
  return (
    <Box
      className="index-header text-center"
      sx={{
        position: 'relative',
        height: '500px',
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        '&::before': {
          content: '""',
          position: 'absolute',
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          width: '100%',
          height: '100%',
          backgroundImage: 'linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5))',
          zIndex: 1,
        }
      }}
    >
      <Image
        fill
        src="/path/to/your/background.jpg"
        alt="Image alt"
        style={{ objectFit: "cover"}}
      />
      <Box
        sx={{ zIndex: 2, width: '30%' }}
      >
        <Typography variant="h1" sx={{ color: 'white', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
          Title
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="body2" sx={{ color: 'white', mt: 0, mb: 4, fontSize: '20px' }}>
          Sub-title
        </Typography>
        <SearchBar />
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this code looks much much much better